# Disable scp password prompt

Tags: passwords, scp

I have a user ID set up on a server that doesn't require a password.  I'd like to be able to use scp to transfer a file from it.  My problem is scp keeps asking for my password even though there isn't one; I can telnet to the server and log on without the password.  Is there any option (-o) I can specify to disable the password prompt?  Using keys is not an option.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help writing software. You should consider asking on http://superuser.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I'm guessing you might have to set PermitEmptyPasswords to Yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config as per the instructions [here](http://www.rayber.com/2011/07/ssh-with-empty-password-and-no-ssh-keys.html).